# Ethnography and Qualitative Research Staying Relevant

Tags: research, qualitative-analysis, ethnography

How must **ethnography** be re-calibrated for a *moment* driven by the study of complex phenomena like **globalization** or **mass mediation**, things ethnography was decidedly **not** concocted to study?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing what the User Experience question is that you're asking. As per the [FAQ] "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."* What is the problem that you face that you need an answer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethnography **has** been 're-calibrated' for Computer-Mediated Communication and related complex cultural phenomena, because anthropology, sociology and psychology (to name some) have never stop analysing them.

> Technologically mediated environments prevent researchers from
>   directly observing research participants. The online environment
>   requires adjustments in how ethnographers define the setting of their
>   research, conduct participant observation and interviews, obtain
>   access to settings and research subjects, and deal with the ethical
>   dilemmas posed by the medium.

Some publications / articles you can check, just to name a few:

- [Ethnography goes online: towards a user-centred methodology to research interpersonal communication on the internet](http://qrj.sagepub.com/content/11/6/716.abstract)
- [Ethnographic Approaches to the Internet and Computer-Mediated Communication](http://jce.sagepub.com/content/38/1/52)
- [Virtual Ethnography: Interactive Interviewing Online as Method](http://www.cjlt.ca/index.php/cjlt/article/view/40/37)
- [The Boundaries of Ethnography](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jtb17/blogs/j_t_bernardo/2012/01/the-boundaries-of-ethnography.html)

If you think the subjects ethnology was not concocted to study in its beginning are not complex, take a second look at ties of kinship or religious studies. Culture always means a complex analysis!